# Java: KeyListener

Tags: java, keylistener

I was just wondering if it was possible to add a key listener to components outside a java application. In other words, what do I need to do in order to detect the keys typed when the focus isn't on the java application?

Thanks in advance,

S.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489037/java-system-wide-keyboard-and-mouse-state

Comment: It can be done with Java but would require JNA or JNI if you wanted to create a keylogger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't detect key events to programs running outside of your Java application.  It you want to do that, you'll have to write your program in a native language (C, C++, etc.)

Comment: Well that sucks. Thanks for the help.